# Optimize bootup sequence

Tags: 11.04, boot, optimization

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 (upgraded from 10.10) and suffering really high bootup times. It got so annoying, that I decided to dive into bootchart analysis myself. Therefore I installed bootchart and restarted the system [which generated this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZh2p.jpg).

However, I'm not really experienced in reading such stuff. What causes the long bootup sequence?

**Edit:**

Here is the output of hdparm -i /dev/sda:

```
/dev/sda:

Model=SAMSUNG HD501LJ, FwRev=CR100-12, SerialNo=S0MUJ1EQ102621
Config={ Fixed }
RawCHS=16383/16/63, TrkSize=34902, SectSize=554, ECCbytes=4
BuffType=DualPortCache, BuffSize=16384kB, MaxMultSect=16, MultSect=16
CurCHS=16383/16/63, CurSects=16514064, LBA=yes, LBAsects=976773168
IORDY=on/off, tPIO={min:120,w/IORDY:120}, tDMA={min:120,rec:120}
PIO modes:  pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
DMA modes:  mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 
UDMA modes: udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
AdvancedPM=no WriteCache=enabled
Drive conforms to: unknown:  ATA/ATAPI-3,4,5,6,7

* signifies the current active mode
```

And here the output of hdparm -tT /dev/sda

```
/dev/sda:
Timing cached reads:   2410 MB in  2.00 seconds = 1205.26 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 258 MB in  3.02 seconds =  85.50 MB/sec
```

Comment: Your disk seems slow. What does `sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda` say? What about `sudo hdparm -i /dav/sda`?

Comment: You have MySQL, Postgres and Apache start on boot? Is this a server? Probably you can shave off a few more seconds if you leave it out of boot if it's a desktop.

Comment: Are you booting from an external drive?

Comment: I'd recommend trying out server software on virtualbox. Makes them easier to manage and saves your desktop from clutter. Development is also easier on separated installations.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! Yes, I'm currently booting MySQL, Postgres and Apache on boot - shouldn't do that, you're right. Will look at the virtualbox suggestion. And yes, I'm booting from a external drive - at the moment there's no other way. @Seppo: The hdparm parameters where set by the system, not by me. To be honest, I'm not really sure where to change them. After reading through the manpage of hdparm, I read that -tT performs benchmarks which should be not really necessary on every boot. But why -i? It just returns id info.

Comment: @ubuntudroid I'm just interested in the numbers the benchmark produces. It tells a lot about your drive. I'm not suggesting that you run it every boot.

Comment: Removed Postgres, MySQL and Apache from startup sequence - sadly this didn't make much of a difference...

Comment: Added hdparm outputs

Comment: hdparm seems normal and is configured right.

Answer (score 1):

I found similar issues and after installing and fretting with the bootchart app I had a look at Georges Techblog here which covered the issues of Unity boot time:

[Georges tech blog](http://georgovassilis.blogspot.com/2011/05/speeding-up-ubuntu-1104-boot-time.html)

They really seemed to get to grips with issues that I could then use to really improve my boot time with unity. Some I understood, some I have to say ...were beyond my understanding

Apologies if you have seen this before but he also did a more recent update which may help

I would also as a matter of course look at what things you have starting up automatically

Hit the super key (windows key) and type *Startup Applications* and you can then (de)select things you do not need to start up ...it might also help alongside the more complex things

Comment: Thanks for the link, will have a look at the article. As for the startup applications: I've already searched through the list, but there was absolutely nothing unusual there which could explain the long boot times...

Comment: Checked out all the tips, unfortunately to no avail... :( However these seem to be great tips in general!

Comment: it was rather interesting although I have to be honest and say I did not do all of them as I did not understand them all.it did knocks seconds off though 8-10 in all for me added to other 'stuff and clutter'